# WebView.getUrl() returns null because page not done loading

Tags: android, webview, geturl

I want to get the url of the webview.  However, the method calls before the page is done loading so it always returns with null.  Any way around this?  Thanks.

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webView);

webView.loadUrl(myURL);

//page is not done loading yet
String url = webView.getUrl(); //returns null
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please explain more clearly and post the code you are using.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179212/webview-geturl-returns-null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a `WebViewClient` and overriding the `onPageFinished(...)` method. I've never done it but something like this might work...

```
String theUrl;
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webView);

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        theUrl = url;
    }

});

webView.loadUrl(myURL);
```

Comment: Is there a way to continually check the url?  (Example: advancing to another activity when the url changes).

Comment: According to the docs, `onPageFinished(...)` will be called every time the main frame of any web page has finished loading in the `WebView` object. The code is just an example and, as I said, not something I've used before. Try putting a `startActivity(...)` call in the `onPageFinished(...)` method instead of my example of `theUrl = url`.

Comment: What do you put inside the startActivity?

Comment: I don't know, what sort of `Activity` do you want to start? You do it the same way as starting any `Activity`. Create an `Intent` and pass it into `startActivity(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Create a subclass of `WebViewClient` which overrides [onPageStarted(webView, url, favicon)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageStarted%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29) and set it to your `WebView` (using `setWebViewClient()`).
 You'll have the url of the page which is loading or displayed.

Comment: So I would make a class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient, then override onPageStarted?  What would I put inside that method, and how exactly do I use setWebViewClient()?
Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you do the same things than in the post of Squonk but you override `onPageStarted` instead of `onPageFinished`. Doing this, your attribute `theUrl` will always contain the current url of the WebView