# how to check if webview URL contains a string?

Tags: android

I am trying to                                   make my app share a valid URL only, else show a toast. i am checking if                                                                                                                                      the URL contains a particular string. if yes, share the link,                                                          however, i am getting an exception-

```
public void sharevideo() {
    String url = webView.getUrl();
    if (url.contains("play;_ylt=")) {
        // video_is_being_played
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share..."));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "cannot share this",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

logs included-

```
 06-11 06:54:08.120: E/InputEventReceiver(9116): Exception dispatching input event.
    06-11 06:54:08.120: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.sharevideo(MainActivity.java:446)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:428)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3694)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:404)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:185)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:655)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:948)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:191)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1206)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3260)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4068)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3830)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.onTouchEvent(ListViewCompat.java:120)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8488)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2400)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2093)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer.dispatchTouchEvent(PopupWindow.java:1744)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8683)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4129)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3995)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3550)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3603)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3569)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3686)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3577)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3743)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3550)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3603)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3569)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3577)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3550)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5813)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5787)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5758)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5903)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:681)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(<Xposed>)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    06-11 06:54:08.122: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9116):   at com.android.internal.os.Z
    06-11 06:54:08.123: D/AndroidRuntime(9116): Shutting down VM
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116): Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 9116
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.sharevideo(MainActivity.java:446)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:428)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3694)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:404)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:185)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:655)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:948)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:191)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1206)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3260)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4068)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3830)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.onTouchEvent(ListViewCompat.java:120)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8488)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2400)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2093)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer.dispatchTouchEvent(PopupWindow.java:1744)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8683)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4129)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3995)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3550)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3603)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3569)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3686)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3577)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3743)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3550)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3603)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3569)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3577)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3550)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5813)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5787)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5758)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5903)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:681)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(<Xposed>)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    06-11 06:54:08.125: E/AndroidRuntime(9116):     at java.lang.reflect.Meth
```

Comment: In your code `webView.getUrl()` is returning null. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773037/webview-geturl-returns-null-because-page-not-done-loading

Comment: i cant do this in WebViewClient

Comment: it works totally fine without the if else statements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @abbie, did my answers solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your `webView` object is initialized or exists in that scope?

It would also be wise to check via a `Toast` object or debug message what URL you receive, i.e. what `getUrl()` returns.

Lastly, try using the method `.matches(String)` instead of `.contains(CharSequence)`.

Comment: What can't you use?

Comment: @abbie: Can you please point out where you initialized `webView`?